# Best choice for Microsoft Paint for Mac?

Tags: drawing

Are there any Mac apps that are very similar to Microsoft Paint besides Paintbrush and Paint.net? I've tried those apps but found a lot of quirkiness and am looking for something more polished and user friendly.

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking for something that is very simple. For example, without photo editing functions like special effects, and without advanced illustration functions like multiple paint brushes. Just for Nanking simple sketches and diagrams.

Comment: so than, what is wrong with simple Paintbrush?

Answer (score 0):

[Corel Painter](http://www.corel.com/us/free-trials/?cat=cat4130083&rootCat=cat3610091&storeKey=us&languageCode=en) & family, [StudioArtist](http://synthetik.com) - depends what you're really after…

Add detail to your question to hone down the answers

Answer (score 0):

For future references you might want to book mark this web site that will help you searching for alternatives, named "Alternativeto".

GIMP made it to the top of they list, but there is multitude of alterntives listed.

> Open Source by Free Software Fondation (GNU) | Mac, Windows, Linux,
>   BSD, Haiku
>
> GIMP is a freely distributed program for such tasks as photo
>   retouching, image composition and image authoring. It can be used as a
>   simple paint program, an expert quality photo retouching program, an
>   online...

http://alternativeto.net/software/microsoft-paint/?platform=mac